# Movable Type: How to replace " with &quot;

Tags: regex, movabletype

I am trying to replace only `"` with `&quot;` within `EntryBody`

I tried `<mt:entrybody replace=""","&quot;">` but this seems to not work. Version is MT5.02 and I don't want to use `<mt:entrybody encode_html="1">`

What I am trying to do is import all entires using CSV(comma separated) format(clients request) and `"` (quotation mark) inside EntryBody gives me syntax errors. I can't use `encode_html` because this encodes links(`<a href=""></a>`) to entities and I don't want that.

Any advice?

Comment: It would most likely be `replace='"','&quot;'` or `replace="\"","&quot;"` -- have you tried either of those?

Comment: it worked! I didnt realize ' works

Comment: Ugg... stuff that looks like XML but isn't. No wonder people have a hard time figuring out the syntax / lexical details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of these should work.

```
"\"","&quot;"
'"','&quot;'
```